# SQL Server continue series of inserts from Select statements despite errors(?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-insert, openrowset

I have a large file of SQL statements that are lined up as follows:

```
 INSERT INTO [table here]
    SELECT [columns]
    FROM OPENROWSET(xlsx tab 1)

INSERT INTO [table here]
    SELECT [columns]
    FROM OPENROWSET(xlsx tab 2)

... etc etc...
```

The problem is that sometimes XLSX tab #2 (or 22) does not exist and may cause an error and the entire series of statements fails.

Is there a way to get each statement to execute as though they were their own query or ignore the error and continue?

Thanks!

Comment: You could wrap each insert in a try/catch if you don't care that some of the inserts may not happen. That sounds a bit brittle to me but it would do what you are asking.

Comment: @SeanLange method is probably best. Another way is a cursor to determine how many tabs exists and then dynamically build the insert statements. Since you already have most of the code written though, i'd just wrap it in TRY/CATCH

Comment: I tried BEGIN TRY/END TRY and CATCH but it still errors/rolls back entire block. IDK if this has something to do with OPENROWSET - I also tried using "GO" but that didn't work either

Comment: alright I'm sorry - I didn't have "GO" on it's own line, it seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error Handling in SQLServer is tricky.There some errors that abort entire batch,some which abort entire session,errors which abort session can't be caught and can't be retried from SSMS itself

In your case,if you want one insert ,not to be affected by another..Try separating them with [BATCH SEPARATOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go) `GO`

```
INSERT INTO 
SELECT 
GO

INSERT
SELECT
GO
```

**Reference and further reading :**
[Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

Comment: OK this is working - the problem is that I didn't have a carriage return after "GO" so it wasn't on it's on line previously.  I updated that and it is working fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thinking you want something along these lines.

```
begin try
    INSERT INTO [table here]
        SELECT [columns]
        FROM OPENROWSET(xlsx tab 1)
end try
begin catch
    select 'Tab1 errored'
end catch

begin try
    INSERT INTO [table here]
        SELECT [columns]
        FROM OPENROWSET(xlsx tab 2)
end try
begin catch
    select 'Tab2 errored'
end catch
```